# How to do a conditional Vlookup

Tags: excel

I have a table like the picture below

[image]

My purpose I to look up for the score of A2 in class B WITH a formula (no sort, filter, ..) - could it be done in Excel 2010?

Comment: http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/04/21/vlookup-on-two-columns/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
{=INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(E2&F2,$A$2:$A$7&$B$2:$B$7,0),1)}
```

You need to key in the formula:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(E2&F2,$A$2:$A$7&$B$2:$B$7,0),1)
```

And then, before hitting enter, hold down "control+shift" while hitting enter. This causes the formula to be an "array" formula. If you just hit enter the formula doesn't work.

Here's what my test looked like on screen:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

The formula is in G2.

If you use R1C1 mode (which everyone should because it is much easier to debug spreadsheets) then the formula looks like this:

```
{=INDEX(R2C3:R7C3,MATCH(RC[-2]&RC[-1],R2C1:R7C1&R2C2:R7C2,0),1)}
```